# how to duplicate divs within divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am quite new to all of this. I want to ask for help and some advice how to duplicate example of DIV which contains more DIV within it. What I am trying to achieve is on click of button Add author to duplicate whole main div with divs within and also append a number to each ID so on the input to database it won't create a mess.
My HTML example is under:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 var newNum = 1;
 cloneMe = function (el) {
     var newElem = el.clone().attr('id', 'author' + newNum);
     newElem.children().each(function (index, elem) {
         $(elem).attr('id', $(elem).attr('id') + newNum).attr('name', $(elem).attr('name') + newNum);
     });
     $('#cloneb').before(newElem);
     $('#delete_name' + newNum).html('<p id="rem_field"><a href="#"><span>Delete Line</span></a></p>');
     newNum++;
 };

 $('p#rem_field').live('click', function () {
     $(this).parents('div').remove();
     return false;
 });
</script>

<form name="submit" action="submit.php" method="GET">
    <div class="author" id="author" name="author">
        <div class="boxtitle" id="boxtitle" name="boxtitle" >
            <input  type="text" class="titleauthor" id="title" name="title">
            <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">Title</p></div>
        <div class="box" id="box" name="box">
            <input  type="text" class="nameauthor" id="f_name" name="f_name">
            <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">First name</p></div>
        <div class="box" id="box" name="box">
            <input type="text" class="nameauthor" id="l_name" name="l_name">
            <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">Last name</p></div>
        <div class="box" id="box" name="box">
            <input type="text" class="nameauthor" id="email" name="email">
            <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">E-mail address</p></div>
        <div class="checboxauthor" id="checkboxauthor" name="checboxauthor">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check">
           <p class="help-block" id="help-block" name="help-block">Contact</p></div>
        <div class="boxbutton" id="boxbutton" name="boxbutton">
        <button type="button" class="button" id="AuthorButton" onclick="cloneMe($('#author'));"/> Add author</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/te2fmnqy/)**

As you can see there is some Javascript for cloning but I don't know why it is not working. Any of your advice is appreciated. Also sorry if it was already asked. 
Thanks

Comment: This is jQuery (tag added), and the `live()` method is deprecated. Use `on()`.

Comment: Hi, I have replaced live() with on() but still not working. thanks anyways

Comment: Also, you're not closing your `document.ready` function.

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/te2fmnqy/1

Comment: Make sure you're watching your console. Both of those issues threw errors.

Comment: Isherwood seem to have solved the issue you have. But it depends on, how much of that stuff you're trying to do, since it can be a tedious job to hardcode everything. I must admit I haven't tried this myself, but it sounds like something that could be helpful to you: http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem is how you're adding the new element to the document. I'd create a wrapper element and simply append to it:

```
<div id="authorlist">
    <div class="author" id="author" name="author">

$('#authorlist').append(newElem);
```

**[Simplified Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/te2fmnqy/2/)**

Comment: And one more question, how would I achieve to add option to remove duplication if added by accident?

Comment: Please don't add new questions in comments. Go ahead and add a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I want to introduce you to the Range object, which is a great solution to this and many other problems, 
1. Make a range object using: `var range = document.createRange();` /*Check references for making this on IE*/
2. Select div content with `range.selectNodeContents(divElement);`
3. Clone its contents `var clone = range.cloneContents();`
4. You append the clone to the other div, `otherDiv.appendChild(clone);`